# Intex pool decking foundation?

Tags: foundation, pool

I've been building a decking area which is 17ft x 17ft, the decking is to be the base for an Intex 16ft diameter pool, calculations show that the weight of this pool when filled with be approx. 18 tonnes.

To support this I've constructed a 5 inch concrete wall all around the inside of the decking base, which is as tall as the wood, inside the concrete I am filling the base with sand, right up to the underneath of the decking.

The question is, will this be enough to support the pool?

Comment: I personally would just use a sand base for the pool. This allows the bottom to not get punctured by a sliver, and also allows the bottom to feel softer under your feet.